# Setting the value of a hidden input field in django template

Tags: python, html, django

I have a hidden field defined in my django template,value of which is passed from the view in the context

```
<input type="hidden" value={{name}}></input>
```

I notice a strange problem. If the value in the context is a multiword string like "John Doe", then the input box is

```
<input type="hidden" value="John" doe></input>
```

What is the reason behind this and how can it be fixed ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around it.